# how to stream or share files from Linux to Android?

Tags: applications, linux, networking, file-management, video-streaming

How can I browse a Linux directory over wi-fi to list files from Linux on Android for video streaming on Android?

While I don't mind [mucking about](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78748/17056) in the CLI with Linux would want to do this as painlessly as possible.

Comment: Use a [file manager with networking capabilities](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156) (disclosure: link goes to my site)? Some support SSH, many support Samba/CIFS. For the latter, you'ld need to setup a Samba share on your Linux machine (which isn't that difficult).

Comment: @xavier_fakerat  "From now you can access files in your android device on Linux PC" -- I'm asking for the inverse operation.

Comment: @Thufir An idea would be an FTP server running on your computer, to which you could connect your phone via Wi-Fi. If it works for extremes such as browsing a Nintendo 3DS' SD card from within Android, it is bound to allow you to do the same with Linux as target.

Comment: how about using a dlna server on linux and then install a dlna client on your Android device?